# Find owner of coupon

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, get-posts

I'm attempting to run a function for a user if they have a certain coupon.
I'm using the plugin [Smart Coupons](https://www.woothemes.com/products/smart-coupons/) to generate coupons with prefixes and suffixes.

I can get a list of all the coupons in the store with get_posts, but get_posts doesn't allow me to find out who the coupon 'belongs' to.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby'          => 'title',
    'order'            => 'asc',
    'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
    'post_status'      => 'published',
    'date_query'    => array(
        'column'  => 'post_date',
        'year'   => '2016'
    )
);


$coupons = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $coupons as $coupon ) {
    // Get the name of each coupon
    $coupon_name = $coupon->post_title;

    if ((0 === strpos($coupon_name, 'nu')) && (20 === strpos($coupon_name, 'sa399'))) {
        $couponthree = $coupon_name;
        echo '399 Dollar Coupon:' . $couponthree . '<br>';

    } else {
        if ((0 === strpos($coupon_name, 'nu')) && (20 === strpos($coupon_name, 'sa'))) {
            $couponten = $coupon_name;
            echo '10 Dollar Coupon:' . $couponten . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to know the `customer_email` for each of the `$coupon_name`.

And then I want to be able to run a function against each person that has either of the two coupons I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about $coupon->customer_email; ?

Comment: I don't know why that eluded me - that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Wow! I wasn't even sure if it would help. ;-)